# Many answers, each one with many votes

Tags: feature-request, badges, searching, up-votes

Just by curiosity: [This recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258284/is-the-matrix-left2m-choose-2j-i-right-i-j-12m-1-nonsingular) has had five answers so far, and ***each answer has gotten more than 10 upvotes***. I think this is quite exceptional (unless the questions are CW of course). How would one do a search for this kind of questions on the site? And why not create a silver badge - or even a gold badge - for the OP who has the merit of asking a question which triggers so many great answers?

Comment: This sounds like a job for the Stackexchange Data Explorer.

Comment: To add to Emil Jeřábek's comment, links to some basic info about SEDE are available [in the data-explorer tag-wiki](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes indeed. It is about a query, and I hope a specialist can provide the "code" in less than one minute. :) And then there is the badge suggestion.

Comment: @Wolfgang Is this query along the lines of what you wanted: [Questions with all answers having at least given score](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/611696/questions-with-all-answers-having-at-least-given-score).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes it does, thank you! Just wondering why the current question doesn't appear in the list...

Comment: Well as you probably know (or you can learn from the links mentioned in previous comments), data in SEDE are updated once a week. So you can either wait a bit or change the parameters to [4 answers with score at least 8](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/611696/questions-with-all-answers-having-at-least-given-score?NumberOfAnswers=4&MinScore=8) and then you will find the question (in the current version of the data in SEDE) with score 17, 4 answers and lowest answer score 8.

Comment: OK,  thank you very much!